# Car won't come out of reverse gear unless rolling

Tags: transmission, manual-transmission, gears

I have a 1989 Nissan Skyline R31 and when I put it into reverse, it will refuse to come back out of gear. The clutch was changed a few thousand km's ago and has had this problem recently. The only possible way to get the car into neutral from reverse is to release the brakes and let the car roll while forcing it out of reverse. The problem is the same whether the car is running or not. Any help greatly appreciated.

Comment: does it come out of reverse when the engine isn't running? is there any adjustment you can do to the pedal? any play in the linkage?

Comment: How are gear changes between all the forward gears?  Do they work; is it difficult to change or pretty normal or do you have to double clutch or anything like that?

Comment: With it not wanting to come out of reverse whether the engine is running or not, leads me to believe there is an internal issue with the transmission. If it was hard to get into/out of gear with the engine running, yet easy in/out with it off, this would lead me to believe the clutch hydraulics needed bled (or cable adjustment if so equipped). I'm not real positive at this point, but that's where I'm leaning.

Comment: Can you shift gears while the car is parked?

Answer (score 1):

This sounds like a problem with the shifter linkage; Had a problem similar on a Nissan that came through the garage, though not a swanky skyline. It just needed unbolting and then pushing through the little shifter apeture until it stopped moving, as the previous mechanic (Apprentice who did a gearbox gasket replacement and throw-out bearing replacement) hadn't pushed it all the way through. It has little flat spots to stop it sliding all the way out again. Look for a repair manual and try following that; It'll hopefully have in-depth information.

I'd also say, however, this 'could' (I say 'could' because it's not very likely, however still possible) that the syncronisers have worn out. I also can't find out about any TSBs seeing as it's such an old vehicle, but there's all the chance that the reverse gears could have a common problem.

There is a check you can do: If you push the clutch down and you get free movement in neutral and the gears other than reverse, it's almost certainly the clutch or a serious transmission problem, or perhaps the syncros have worn to the point of being completely useless. If there's trouble getting it into a couple of gears or all with or without the clutch pressed down, it's pretty likely to be a bad shifter linkage not being fully 'engaged' or 'seated' in it's receiver. (Calling it that because I can't think of the correct terminology off the top of my head)

Things to do quickly: 
1: Pump The Clutch.
 - Even if it's not a hydraulic clutch (I don't know much about the older cars) pump the clutch, as cable-actuated components may get pinched and may free up again after being pumped repetitively and all the way down a load of times.
2:Check out For Leaks!
 - Quite easy to overlook, a low fluid level can actually inhibit certain gears as I found on my old Peugot 405 and Vauxhall Corsa B.
3: Check any modifications.
  - Short-Throw Shifter? Different gearbox mount? Some sports-type clutch that could be too thick for the transmission? Any of these modifications could *potentially* cause problems with shifting, not to mention having a short throw shifter that isn't limited; If it's not a limit-able type for the selector throw, it'll chew up the selectors.

Answer (score 0):

My truck did that for a while but only it wouldnt go into reverse. What I had to do was drive it around in 4 wheel drive and then sinco pump the clutch into first then reverse.. Idrk but that sounds like what you might wanna try so good luck! I mean what do I know im only 15..

Comment: This vehicle, to my understanding, does not have a switchable 4 wheel drive. By 'sinco' pump, do you mean double-declutch? For example, in first gear; Clutch down, neutral, clutch up, clutch down, desired gear, clutch up?

Comment: no i ment like pump the clutch five times go into first and then to neutral then reverse.

Comment: but i also broke my front axel so i cant back up anymore. because my truck wont go into 4 wheel drive because I blew out a hub too so yeah.. i dont really know but thats what I had to do before I got it broke

Comment: OH, that'll be because your clutch system needs bleeding - BADLY. Air in the hydralic clutch system causes this, so get to a mechanic and ask him to bleed it. It'll work like normal again. And how did you break your axle?! :P Good luck getting that fixed, lol.

Comment: i broke my axle by beating on it too hard while wheeling with friends and now it just wont go into 4 wheel drive. so idk if i really broke it but yeahhh. im looking for a new one for sure and thanks for the tips and luck! @yollooool